# ThenInclude de um List

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core

Tenho uma entidade chamada **Team** (imagem 1) que por sua vez tem uma ICollection de **UserTeam** (imagem 2) que por sua vez tem uma ICollection **ApplicationUser** chamada Member.

**Objetivo:** retornar uma lista de **teams** com seus **members**

**Restrição:** não posso alterar a estrutura das entidades.

*Linguagem:* c-sharp
*Framework:* dotnet Core 2.0

```csharp
var query = _context.Team.AsQueryable().AsNoTracking() 
.Include(x => x.Account) 
.Include(x => x.UserTeam) 
.Where(x => x.Id == teamId && x.Deleted == false);
```

[image: Team]

[image: Team]

[image: query]

Comment: Qual é o problema? Ps.: evite utilizar imagens e apresente o seu código como texto na pergunta. É sempre importante ter um [MCVE]

Comment: Leandro Angelo, basta ler o objetivo para entender. O código importante foi escrito na pergunta. Tem certeza que leu toda pergunta ?

Comment: Não seria colocar um .ToList() depois do where ?

Comment: Não. Geralmente usamos o Include para o linq fazer o "Join" mas quando tem mais de um nível (Include do UserTeam e Include do Member no UserTeam), eu não sei como resolver.

Comment: @Carlinhos, não, as imagens são bloqueadas aqui, por isso é importante incluir o código como texto

Comment: @LeandroAngelo bloquear stackoverflow é sacanagem heim ? rs

Comment: As imagens não são hospedadas no stack overflow e é comum bloqueá-las. Para evitar intervenções, votos negativos e remoções procure sempre adicionar os códigos como texto e formatados apropriadamente.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Não sei se entendi direito mas acho que você está querendo buscar os membros do time na mesma consulta.
Use `.ThenInclude(p => p.Member)` para fazer o join de UserTeam e Member:

```
var query = _context.Team.AsQueryable().AsNoTracking() 
            .Include(x => x.Account) 
            .Include(x => x.UserTeam)
                 .ThenInclude(p => p.Member)
            .Where(x => x.Id == teamId && x.Deleted == false);
```

Comment: Era isso mesmo. 
O problema é que não estava aparecendo no intellisense quando montava a expressão lambda mas mesmo sem aparecer, funciona. Obrigado